# connect camera to virtual machine VMware Workstation 14

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware, hyper-v, vmware-workstation

I have a paid version of VMware Workstation 14.
I mostly use a few VM's running simultaneously.
I tried to create a VM for editing, including some editing SW (like Adobe's SW). Everything went smooth, until I tried to connect the camera (DSLR) to the VM in order to control it via the PC. But, then the connected camera didn't appear on the VM. It appears only in the host computer.
Is it possible?
If not, does Hyper-V will be more suitable for this (I prefer to find a solution based on VMware, due to it supports well of Linux distro)?

Host PC: Win 10 PRO
VM: Windows 10 PRO

Answer (score 4):

I have a VMWare Workstation 15 Pro on my Windows 10 (Host). I have attached an image showing the 2 easy steps:

---

[VMWare Workstation(15 Pro): Connect Integrated Webcam To Running Guest OS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZrnbS.png)

1. Power up your Guest OS in VMWare Workstation
2. Below the Guest OS screen, you will see a bar with hardware shortcuts for the Guest OS
3. On the bar's right there are icons for "Hard Disk", "Network Adapter", "Mouse"...
4. Find "Integrated Webcam" > "Connect (Disconnect from Host)"

This will disconnect the integrated cam of your device from your Host OS and connect it to the Guest OS. If you have multiple Guest OS running, you can simply follow the above steps to change the integrated-cam connection to any OS from previously connected Host or Guest OS.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried looking in the settings of the VM for the setting to connect/disconnect USB devices?

Example:

```
VM > Removable Devices > Device Name > Connect (Disconnect from host)
```

Additional information is available in the docs: https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/14.0/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-E003456F-EB94-4B53-9082-293D9617CB5A.html

Comment: Yes, Sure.
The camera is not showing (also other some devices) in the menu. But, it does show under Device Manager -> Action -> Devices and Printers

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. You should add a hardware-USB Controller in setting. Then you can see all the USB devices in the removable devices context menu.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread but in case anyone else is searching for answers:

You may need to start the VMWare USB Arbitration Service (it may not start by default).

- Ctrl + R then `services.msc`
- Search for VMWare USB Arbitration Service and then start.

Once this service is started you can then view the device in the VMWare settings.